# How to obtain affected rows in PDO (PHP) after calling execute method of PDOStatement class

Tags: php, c++, mysql, pdo

I have a question. I am building an C++ app that works with PDO extension in PHP.

Suppose i have a script that is like that :

```
$sth->bindParam(':calories', $calories);
$sth->bindParam(':colour', $colour);
$sth->execute();
```

with some sort prepared statement above

I wanna know if I can tweak at PHP internals and get the affected rows value of execute method. Just like in `mysqli` we have affected rows property unfortunately we do not have it in pdo or have to dig deep to find it. Of course that is without calling `$sth->rowCount();`
Thanks.

Comment: two questions, if you please. 1. Why do you need a row count? 2. why without calling $sth->rowCount(); Thanks.

Comment: I need to know the number of rows affected. I am performing an analysis without the user specifically calling for rowCount function.